# What is the difference between referencing pointers in a function

Tags: c

I'm creating a function which modifies a variable so it can be used by the function referencing it (parent function?).

Is there a difference between using '&x' compared to using 'z' in the code below?

```
void changeX(int *p);

int main(void) {
  int x = 10;
  printf("%d\n",x);

  int *z = &x;
  changeX(z);
  printf("%d\n",x);

  // or

  changeX(&x);
  printf("%d\n",x);
  return 0;
}

void changeX(int *p){
  *p = *p + *p;
}
```

wildplasser made a good point, updated to show where I have gotten each value in the output.

Output is:

```
10
20
40
```

Both produce the same outcome (change x in the same way), but is there a non-obvious difference between them?

Thanks for the answers in the comments. It makes sense to me now.

Comment: Where does the output come from?

Comment: Answer the question "What address does pointer `z` hold as its value?" If your answer is "The address of `x`." -- then it makes no difference whether you pass `&x` or `p` as both pass the same address. Therefore `p` in `changeX` will hold the same address as its value regardless. Remember a pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value. Your job is to know what address the pointer points to.

Comment: There is no difference between the two cases.   The value of `p` passed to each call of `changeX()` is `&x`  (i.e. the address of `x`).   So all three operations involving `*p`  in the function affect `x`.

Answer (score 0):

The first call initializes the parameter from the argument `z`, i.e., the value of the argument is the value of the pointer `z`, which was initialized to be `&x`, a pointer value that points to the object `x.` The second call initializes the parameter from the argument `&x`, which is a pointer value that points to the object `x`. There is no functional difference between the two calls. In both cases, the parameter `p` in the function will have the exact same value, a pointer value that points to `x`, the only difference is where that value came from at the point where function was called…

Comment: You have the calls backwards. The first is the value of the pointer ```z```.